# Asp.net Google Sign In

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-signin, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

I'm trying to implement Google Sign In in my ASP.net application. 
I have implemented the javascript code from [Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) and that works but I need to store a Google User ID in my Database for identification in future logins.

The page states that I shouldn't use the `profile.getId` but I should send the `googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token` to the backend and validate this token.

Well I've sent this huge bundle of characters to the backend but I can't seem to figure out how to validate this bundle of characters and retrieve a useful identification ID (which should stay the same for a Google User) from this data bundle.

I've taken a look at:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Google.Apis.Auth.GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload> Sig = Google.Apis.Auth.GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(Request.Form["idToken"], null, true);
 Sig.Wait();
}
```

But this just hangs in my `Page_Load` method.

Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you setup your javascript, but the way I have my setup the page already loaded, so I have an API on the backend that receives the token from the client, then do this to get the payload:

```
GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(Token);
```

The payload will give you all the user's information.