# Google Sign-In on web page, token validated in ASP.NET backend, no client secret used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-signin, google-identity-toolkit, google-identity

I followed instruction given here to expose Google Sign In button.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

To confirm the token on server side, I am calling `GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync()` as described on these answers.

[Asp.net Google Sign In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771542/asp-net-google-sign-in)

[Validate Google Id Token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507020/1459310)

It all works, but I am not using **client secret** on **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** setting on Google Credentials page.

Am I making anything less secure?

Is the need for client secret mitigated by **Authorized Javascript Origins** on **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** setting, because after all client secret is to ensure the legitimacy of the caller?